# Data on IoT use

Tags: data-request, internet-of-things

I am looking for an open/free dataset on IoT use across countries over the years, where I can create my plots or graps illustrating their growing use/diffusion. There exists some data on [www.statista.com](http://www.statista.com), but it is chargeable.

Any suggestions where I can find the data?

Comment: Could you be more specific on what kind of IoT data you are looking for?